# DB2 timestamp equivalent of oracle

Tags: db2

Need help to convert the following oracle timestamp query to DB2.

```
SQL> SELECT TO_CHAR((FROM_TZ(TO_TIMESTAMP('20160311 152656','YYYYMMDD HH24MISS'),'America/New_York')AT TIME ZONE 'America/Los_Angeles'),'YYYYMMDD HH24MISS  TZD') FROM DUAL  ;

TO_CHAR((FROM_TZ(TO_TIM
-----------------------
20160311 122656  PST
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct conversion because DB2 does not store the timezone as part of a timestamp. It is assumed that all timestamps are based on UTC.

You can rewrite the query with the help of [TIMESTAMP_FORMAT](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0007107.html)/[TO_TIMESTAMP](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0054765.html) and [TO_UTC_TIMESTAMP](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0061917.html). The latter function allows to convert a timestamp from the specified timezone to UTC. The special register [CURRENT TIMEZONE](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0005887.html) holds information about the server configuration.

DB2 also has [TO_CHAR](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0007108.html) which is a synonym for [VARCHAR_FORMAT](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0007110.html).